# How to visualize a dynamic graph made in R in a pdf?

Tags: r, plot

I'm making a dynamic plot in R with ggplotly but I don't want it to be displayed in html file nor do I want to program it in RMarkdown. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please share some code and data you used?

Comment: A dynamic plot made in plotly runs in Javascript, so if you want it to remain dynamic it has to be run somewhere that supports JavaScript. I'm not really sure what your question is here.

Comment: I would like the dynamic graph once exported to pdf (in any way) to remain dynamic. For example if I implement a slider bar in R (examples of slider bars https://plotly.com/r/sliders/) when exporting it as a pdf I would like it to be able to be manipulated from the pdf